# Declare trivial protocol conformance for struct in a framework

Tags: swift, struct, linker, protocols

Is it possible to declare that struct a struct, defined in a framework, trivially conforms to a protocol, defined in my app?

Say, for example, I have an API that declares structs for a few widgets modelled in a framework:

```
public struct VagueWidget {
    public let temperature: Float
}

public struct SpecificWidget {
    public let calibratedTemperature: Float
    public let movingAverageTemperature: Float
}

public struct SuperSpecificWidget {
    public let surfaceTemperature: Float
    public let inferredCoreTemperature: Int?
}
```

And then in my application I want to generalise these by way of a protocol.

```
protocol Widget {
    var temperature: Float { get }
}
```

In my application I can declare structs similar to those in the API, and trivially declare them as conforming to the protocol.

```
struct MockWidget {
    let temperature: Float
}

extension MockWidget: Widget {}
```

And then I can declare protocol conformance for the structs in the framework.

```
extension SuperSpecificWidget: Widget {
    var temperature: Float {
        get {
            return surfaceTemperature
        }
    }
}

extension SpecificWidget: Widget {
    var temperature: Float {
        get {
            return calibratedTemperature
        }
    }
}

extension VagueWidget: Widget {}
```

This code compiles, but doesn't link. The trivially conforming `VagueWidget` in the framework which is equivalent to the `MockWidget` in the application results in a missing symbol:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "WidgetAPI.VagueWidget.temperature.getter : Swift.Float", referenced from:
   protocol witness for WidgetApp.Widget.temperature.getter : Swift.Float in conformance WidgetAPI.VagueWidget : WidgetApp.Widget in WidgetApp in AppModel.o
```

Commenting out the trivial protocol conformance for the `VagueWidget` produces code that compiles and runs, but obviously missing the desired protocol conformance. I've added an [example project](https://github.com/blackp/WidgetApp) on github.

**Update:** This appears to be a known issue. I have filed a radar, and it was closed as a duplicate of [20648441](http://www.openradar.appspot.com/20648441).

Answer (score 0):

```
extension WidgetAPI.VagueWidget: Widget {
    var temperature: Float {
        return self.temperature
    }
}
```

Fixes it. Seems to be some sort of conflict with the stored immutable property vs. the computed readonly property in the protocol.

**Update: Nevermind, I just discovered infinite recursion. Still seems like something there**

Comment: Huh, you appear to be correct. I could have sworn I'd tried that, despite the fact that it looks like infinite recursion to me. Thanks!

Comment: @blackp See the update, I was wrong. It's just infinite recursion. Still trying to work through this one. I replicated it in another project.

Comment: Ah okay. Did look like infinite recursion. Comment above where it appeart correct was me running unit tests for the API target, not app. :)

Comment: Honestly, I'm stumped here. I have no problem declaring similar trivial protocols and conformance with standard library structs like `Array`. Signs point to some sort of name collision bug. The obvious but unfortunate workaround is to make your protocol a little less _trivial_ for the time being, haha. Probably worth a radar.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I'm working around it (in my actual project) by choosing contrived-but-not-clashing names in the protocol, which is annoying. I should probably file a radar.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting bug you found. You and Scott H did all the work, but wanted to chime in with some workarounds:

1. Change your models from `struct` to `class`. No idea why this works.
2. Functions also work (i.e. `func temperature() -> Float`).

Both are less than ideal.