# Swift 3.1: Crash when custom error is converted to NSError to access its domain property

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nserror

My Swift app has a custom error system where `MyError` is just a simple class conforming to `Error`. Now the app seems to crash whenever a third-party library (PromiseKit) tries to convert this error to `NSError` and then to access its `domain` property. In my own code, doing this works as expected, so why does it crash in the library and what's the proper way of dealing with it?

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1011d86d8 _hidden#19226_ (__hidden#19178_:1788)
1  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1011cda3c _hidden#19206_ (__hidden#19447_:4045)
2  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1011cda3c _hidden#19206_ (__hidden#19447_:4045)
3  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1011cdc90 swift_getTypeName (__hidden#19406_:1731)
4  AppName                        0x1001dafec specialized (_adHocPrint_unlocked<A, B where ...> (A, Mirror, inout B, isDebugPrint : Bool) -> ()).(printTypeName #1)<A, B where ...> (Any.Type) -> () (MyError.swift)
5  AppName                        0x1001db4f0 specialized specialized _adHocPrint_unlocked<A, B where ...> (A, Mirror, inout B, isDebugPrint : Bool) -> () (MyError.swift)
6  AppName                        0x1001dafb4 specialized _debugPrint_unlocked<A, B where ...> (A, inout B) -> () (MyError.swift)
7  AppName                        0x1001dac00 protocol witness for Error._domain.getter in conformance MyError (MyError.swift)
8  libswiftCore.dylib             0x10104fa14 swift_stdlib_getErrorDomainNSString (__hidden#18979_:140)
9  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1011f96d8 _hidden#21248_ (__hidden#21275_:440)
10 PromiseKit                     0x100dc7d4c Error.isCancelledError.getter (Error.swift:145)
```

Comment: Does your `MyError ` contain domain property?

Comment: Nope. In my own code it seems to fall back to using its type name for the domain value.

Comment: take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981542/declare-trivial-protocol-conformance-for-struct-in-a-framework possibly it will help

Comment: You have to adopt CustomNSError, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/39176551/1187415 for an example

Comment: Did you find a solution? @villapossu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While casting from Error to NSError it is trying to access the `errorCode` and `errorDomain`. Adding these extensions fixed my problem in the same case.

```
extension CustomError: LocalizedError {
    public var errorDescription: String? {
        return "Some localized description"
    }
}

extension CustomError: CustomNSError {
    public static var errorDomain: String {
        return "Some Domain Name"
    }
    public var errorCode: Int {
        return 204 //Should be your custom error code.
    }
}
```

Comment: I apparently made it work by implementing `public var _domain` and `public var _code`, but good to know there is a proper solution to this as well!